# Set web container with timezone properly configured on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic

I am learning how to implement time series with raster on GeoServer following the [image mosaic documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html) .

I am struggling a little bit to understand what this sentence means:

> To support time-series layers, GeoServer needs to be run in a web
>   container that has the timezone properly configured. To set the time
>   zone to be Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), add this switch when
>   launching the Java process:
>
> `-Duser.timezone=GMT`
>
> If using a shapefile as the mosaic index store (see next section),
>   another java process option is needed to enable support for timestamps
>   in shapefile stores:
>
> `-Dorg.geotools.shapefile.datetime=true`

How could I set those? 
Maybe when I start GeoServer?
I am running GeoServer on a docker container.

Comment: how are you running geoserver?

Comment: On  Docker container running the code 'docker start  <container_name>'

Comment: then you need to modify the container's tomcat(?) start up script

Comment: I'm really new on this. I am using this docker image, https://hub.docker.com/r/oscarfonts/geoserver . Maybe should I follow https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/container.html

Comment: Should I run `java -Duser.timezone=GMT` and `java -Dorg.geotools.shapefile.datetime=true` under docker ? I understand it could be a silly question but I really do not know how to go head on this